# qTranslate-X troubleshooting in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, translate, qtranslate-x

I am using qTranslate-X to my WordPress website. The language switching is working, but some line of CSS is showing in the screen:

[image]

```
class="qtranxs-lang-menu qtranxs-lang-menu-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom 
       menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
```

I want the qTranslate-X to my webpage. I just want to remove the CSS showing. It says an example of removing it but I didn't find it:

[image]

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some html, such as the opening `<` to the div, or there is some other mistake in the html that causes it to show as text instead of render as html. Check how you have inserted the code for the language switcher.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the menu settings and remove the qtranslatex language menu
[image]